# Fields Phrase Sometimes Ignored in Dynamic Query

Tags: progress-4gl

With Progress 9.1e, I'm using dynamic queries to make extensible data extracts.

I'm using a query of the form

```
FOR EACH tableName FIELDS( fieldName1 fieldName2 ) NO-LOCK
  WHERE fieldName3 = "Value"
    AND fieldName4 = "AnotherValue"
```

and for some of these queries, notably the ones with few fields in the table, the fields phrase is working and retrieving only the requested.

However, on other queries, interestingly the ones with much longer, and complicated field lists (including arrays etc.), it retrieves the whole record.

I've read various discussions on retrieving additional fields required for joins, but I've simplified my queries so that isn't an issue.

The query specifies no-lock, as does the get-next parameter, so the full-record for exclusive lock shouldn't be relevant either.

Are there other criteria by which Progress decides to select the entire record, and is there any way of stopping it?

Comment: The only time you should care about the FIELDS retrieved is over a slow network connection in order to minimize network traffic.

Comment: @TimKuehn - that may be the intended use, but I'm trying to build a dynamic query process which allows the configuration of additional data to be extracted for "future proofing" and as Progress dynamic queries don't have a SELECT phrase, FIELDS would seem the only option for extracting only the required fields within the selected records. Otherwise, I would have to include a list of required fields in the configuration somewhere else, which is not ideal.

Comment: I don't see how you're going to get the FIELDS to do what you're looking for - according to the 10.2B docs: "When you specify a field list, the AVM might retrieve additional fields or the complete record depending on the type of retrieval operation and the DataServer that provides the record."

In essence, the FIELDS part of the record phrase is a suggestion that the AVM can override for various reasons.

Comment: Future proofing with version 9.1 seems like a strange idea since 9.1e is from way back...

Comment: @Tim #1, I have to respectfully disagree (though not vociferously). We have observed meaningful differences in speed when using FIELDS between remote AppServers and DB servers running side-by-side and connected by ultra-fast networks. We don't actually use FIELDS routinely, and I'm on the fence whether it's worth the extra complexity or not.

Comment: @Tim #2, I saw that doc also, but it specifically mentions DataServer and I assume it meant that 'normal' Progress doesn't have this issue (maybe I'm wrong about that?). I don't care about DataServer and AFAIK, neither does the OP.

Comment: That's interesting - yow meaningful was the difference compared to a self-serve connection?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to this and I'm afraid you might not get one because people running such old Progress versions are often ignored.

It's news to me that you can use FIELDS with a dynamic query, but, the documentation implies that this is true.

I'm curious how you know that it retrieves the whole record, unless you are packet sniffing or something?

Anyway, here are a few things you could check:

- fldisable startup parameter
- rereadfields startup parameter
- confusion with EXCEPT
- the Progress knowledgebase, however I just checked quickly and couldn't find anything useful. I vaguely remember a bug in some versions, of which your question rings a bell

Good luck.

Comment: Hi Thanks! The way I know what is retrieved is that I go through the buffer, getting hBuf:BUFFER-FIELD( i ), and then check hFld:AVAILABLE. When the fields phrase works, I just get the one or two fields available. When it doesn't work - I get the whole record. I wanted to be able to use the fields phrase to select the fields to query.

Comment: TIL that you can use AVAILABLE on fields! Thanks!